# Indy error in Delphi 7: Undeclared identifier: 'hoWantProtocolErrorContent'

Tags: delphi-7, indy, idhttp

When using `TIdHTTP` to send `GET` commands with JSON variables, sometimes the server returns me the error below:

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Using Insomnia for testing JSON results, I see an entire JSON response and a pretty response which clearly indicates what the problem is. I really need that the `TStringStream` be filled even if the response code is not 200.

After a lot of searching, I understand that I should use `HTTPOptions` with the parameters: `hoNoProtocolErrorException` and `hoWantProtocolErrorContent`. However, when using the `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` option, I obtain the following error:

> Undeclared identifier: 'hoWantProtocolErrorContent'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an old version of Indy (is it the one that shipped with Delphi 7?).  Delphi 7 was released in 2002, while the `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` flag was introduced in 2016. Per [New TIdHTTP flags and OnChunkReceived event](https://www.indyproject.org/2016/01/10/new-tidhttp-flags-and-onchunkreceived-event/) in [Indy's blog](https://www.indyproject.org/blog/)):

> **hoWantProtocolErrorContent**: when an HTTP error response is received, `TIdHTTP` normally reads and discards the response’s message body and then raises `EIdHTTPProtocolException` (the message body is available in the `EIdHTTPProtocolException.ErrorMessage` property). If the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` flag is enabled, or the `ResponseCode` number is specified in the request's `AIgnoreReplies` parameter, then no `EIdHTTPProtocolException` is raised, as the caller would like to process the `ResponseCode` manually. Normally `TIdHTTP` would still discard the message body, though. If this new flag is enabled, the message body will no longer be discarded, it will be saved in the caller's target `TStream` like a successful response would be. This flag is disabled by default to preserve existing behavior to discard error message bodies.

So, without the `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` flag, the only way you can access the body data of an HTTP error response is to disable the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` flag (it is disabled by default) and then catch the raised `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception and read its `ErrorMessage` property, eg:

```
var
  Response: TStringStream;

Response := TStringStream.Create('');
try
  try
    IdHTTP1.Get(url, Response);
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      WriteStringToStream(Response, E.ErrorMessage);
  end;
  // use Response.DataString as needed...
finally
  Response.Free;
end;
```

Or simpler:

```
var
  Response: string;

try
  Response := IdHTTP1.Get(url);
except
  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    Response := E.ErrorMessage;
end;
// use Response as needed...
```